# Fetching facebook friends of user

Tags: ios

I am trying to fetch facebook friend list of the user but it returning only count of the friends.Bellow is my code .Is there anything wrong in this code?

```
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                                     parameters:nil
                                     HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                              completionHandler:^(
                                                  FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error
                                                  ) {
                                  NSLog(@"me/friends result=%@",result);

                                  NSLog(@"me/friends error = %@", error.description);

                                  NSArray *friendList = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                                  //[m_allFriends addObjectsFromArray: friendList];
                              }];
}
```

Comment: As I remember you should ask the permissions with authorisation for getting friends. Also, you can get only friend who use your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you registered your app to facebook. Facebook provide only three permission , these permission is by default approved

user_friends Provides access to a person's list of friends that also use your app. This permission is approved by default.

according to this you can get only those friend who use your app.
check this link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends